# Do all modifying methods call the set trap of a Proxy of Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

In order to sync two or multiple arrays I try to use this simple Proxy

```
let a1 = [];
let a2 = [];
let targets = [a1, a2];

let proxy = new Proxy(targets[0], {
    set: (target, property, value) => {
      targets.forEach(t => t[property] = value);
      return true;
    }
});
```

The goal is to replicate all changes on `a1` to `a2`. Tests on Chrome, Firefox and Node indicate **that all methods of Array call a property setter internally**, so that this simple implementation works just fine. But I cannot find any statement if this is guaranteed in any way.

The actual proxy implementation will only look a bit more complicated to deal with nested arrays and objects, but the general question remains the same:
**Is it save to rely on the fact that array methods that modify the array content alyways pass through the set trap?**

See this example:

```js
let a1 = [];
let a2 = [];  

let targets = [a1, a2];
let proxy = new Proxy(targets[0], {
    set: (target, property, value) => {
      targets.forEach(t => t[property] = value);
      return true;
    }
});

proxy[0] = 0;
log('proxy[0] = 0');
proxy[0] = 1;
log('proxy[0] = 1');
proxy.push(1);
log('proxy.push(1)');
proxy.length = 1;
log('proxy.length = 1');
proxy.splice(0, 1, 1, 2, 3);
log('proxy.splice(0, 1, 1, 2, 3)');
proxy.fill(3, 1, 2);
log('proxy.fill(3, 1, 2)');
proxy.shift();
log('proxy.shift()');
proxy.unshift(2);
log('proxy.unshift(2)');

function log(msg) {
  let pre = document.querySelector('pre');
  if (!pre) {
    pre = document.createElement('pre');
    document.body.appendChild(pre);
  }
  pre.innerHTML = msg + '\n' + JSON.stringify(a1) + '\n' + JSON.stringify(a2) + '\n\n' + pre.innerHTML;
}
```

Comment: How are `a1` and `a2` used in the rest of your code?

Comment: @Bergi  When the proxy is used, `a1` and `a2` are not used at all. After we're done with the proxy, we'll continue to use them as usual.

Comment: I guess in that case it would be simpler to use `a1` and make copy `a2 = a1.slice()` after you're done :-)

Comment: @Bergi Hm, this proxy is part of a proxy for objects, but maybe this is really much simpler if I do `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj1))` instead of creating a proxy. Thx for the good suggestion, I will think about it!

Comment: @Bergi ah no, it's not possible, because I only want to sync changes. Properties that didn't change should stay as they are.

Comment: OK I see. However in that case you might need to check upon the array methods on a case-by-case basis whether they really do what you want, as e.g. `shift()` or `unshift()` really affect every single property on the array object so "sync changes" might be unexpected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is safe. All operations that change an array, like assigning to an index, or calling `push` or `splice`, call the Set operation.

For example, with `push`, see [here](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.push);

> b. Perform ? Set(O, ! ToString(len), E, true).

where [Set](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-set-o-p-v-throw) mainly does:

```
>O.[[Set]](P, V, O).
```

which calls the internal method `[[Set]]` of the object in question. If the object in question is a Proxy, then it goes through the process described [here](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-proxy-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots-set-p-v-receiver):

> 6. Let trap be ? GetMethod(handler, "set").
> 7. If trap is undefined, then
>
>    a. Return ? target.[[Set]](P, V, Receiver).
> 8. Let booleanTrapResult be ! ToBoolean(? Call(trap, handler, « target, P, V, Receiver »)).

which explicitly calls the `set` trap on the Proxy, if it exists.